# How to register listeners for multiple firebase references

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with multiple users, and I would like to register a separate listener for each user. This is because a listener on the entire database would be redundant, as every time each user's data is changed, all of the user's data would be returned in the callback.

Say the users are numbered `0 - 25`. I have the following code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("serviceAccountCredentials.json");

var config = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com"
};
var app = admin.initializeApp(config);
var db = admin.database();

var company = db.ref('companies');


for(var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    company_ref = company.child(i);
    company_ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
        console.log("child_added for " + i);
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
    company_ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
        console.log("child_changed for " + i);
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
    company_ref.on("child_removed", function(snapshot){
        console.log("child_removed for " + i);
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

However, this code only registers a listener for user `25`, and it appears that the listeners for the other users all get garbage collected. What is the correct way to do this; do I have to use multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using just one ref to try to store all the refs you need.  Store them in an array of refs instead:

```
var company_ref = []
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    company_ref[i] = company.child(i);
    // do stuff with company_ref[i]
}
```

Also bear in mind that you're using a variable called `id` without ever having defined it, at least not the way you show it.  Maybe you meant `i`?